# How to play sound array in random unique order

Tags: java, arrays, audio

So I've been working with this sound array that holds 4 unique words, and so far, I have successfuly randomized what 4 words are spoken.

```
public void playRandomOrder(int totalWords, int pause) throws InterruptedException {
    Random random = new Random(); // Random number generator for array shuffle
    for (int i =0; i< numWords; i++) {
        int randomPosition = random.nextInt(totalWords); // how many words to sound out (4)
        Sound temp = myWordArray[i];
        myWordArray[i] = myWordArray[randomPosition];
        myWordArray[randomPosition] = temp;
        myWordArray[i].blockingPlay();
        Thread.sleep(pause); 
}
}
```

But my next goal is to play the words out in random order, but playing each word only once, because now, it can play the same word multiple times. Any advice on how to achieve this? I know how to do it with integers, but I've tried for hours on Sound but to no avail.

Comment: You want achieve that next word not same with current word , right ? Or you just want to play them all in random order one word one time ?

Comment: The array says "This is a test", my randomized array so far can say "This this test a", or "this is a a", and I want it to be unique, as in no word can repeat twice. So... "This a test is" or "Is a this test".

Comment: Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comparator to do it by implementing the comparator with a random comparation result .

```
    final Random rand = new Random();
    List<Sound> list = Arrays.asList(myWordArray);
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Sound>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Sound o1, Sound o2) {
        return rand.nextInt() % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1;
    }
    });

    list.toArray(myWordArray);
    for(Sound sound : myWordArray){
         sound.blockingPlay();
         Thread.sleep(1000); // 1000 as the pause
    }
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry if I didn't specify enough, but its not a string array, its an audio array that physically speaks out "This is a test" when you run the program. a WAV file.

Comment: @TheDkmariolink  4 audio in an array , one for 'this' one for 'is ' ... ? Is it the same thing ?

Comment: No, it uses splice points in order to determine how many words to speak out. Its not a string, its  Sound[] myWordArray. The code I posted speaks out the words but not in unique random.

Comment: @TheDkmariolink  It the same thing , just replace String[] with Sound[] and play them in order .

Comment: What do I have to import in order to use Comparator? Tells me it's abstract and cannot be initialized.

Comment: @TheDkmariolink  just like above , implements compare method

Comment: Okay, but since it isn't a string, I cannot print it out, its an audio file.

Comment: @TheDkmariolink   it just for showing array has been reordered

Comment: That dosen't help my situation then, sadly :( I have to make the audio player speak the words in random unique.

Comment: @TheDkmariolink   if `blockingPlay` used to play the invoke sound and it will work .

Comment: Error occurs and it won't play. I replaced "array" with myWordArray, as that is a static array already set as my main array.

Comment: @TheDkmariolink  what is `myWordArray`

Comment: static private Sound[] myWordArray = new Sound[MAX_NUM_WORDS];         The sound array that holds "This is a test" audio along with splicepoints

Comment: Thats the exact same code I have, but results in a thread error in main :(

Comment: Don't have any ideas?

Comment: @TheDkmariolink  I think it will work,'blocking play' seems no need to sleep , post your error .

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Assignment1_ITIS1213.AudioPoem.playRandomUnique(AudioPoem.java:141)
 at Assignment1_ITIS1213.Assignment1_ITIS1213.main(Assignment1_ITIS1213.java:109)

Comment: I wish I could solve this issue, it's really bugging me

Answer (score 0):

shuffle the array first. here the code:

```
public void playRandomOrder(int totalWords, int pause) throws InterruptedException {
    Collections.shuffle(myWordArray);
    for (int i =0; i< numWords; i++) {
        myWordArray[i].blockingPlay();
        Thread.sleep(pause); 
    }
}
```